# Android APP Unable to Access Server

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a mobile first project, when I put https://xxx.sg for the Server under Build path for Android as screenshot below, the generated APP is working in all android phones with KitKat, Lollipop and marshmallow version and able to access the server.

[image]

However, when I changed to https://www.xxx.sg as screenshot below, the APP in the android phones with KitKat and Lollipop are unable to access the server, but the other phone with marshmallow is able to access the server.

[image]

The different is the WWW in the server section for build path.

Any idea to make the APP with WWW build path to be able to access the server in  KitKat, Lollipop and marshmallow version?

There is no specific error message, the APP with WWW build path in KitKat and Lollipop just said unable to access server. Where marshmallow is fine.

Comment: Can you share the LogCat log from a device where the problem is happening?

Comment: which version of MFP is the issue with? 71? 6.3? Please provide complete information to get better support.

Comment: My MFP version is 7.1 and the LogCat is something like "Unable to resolve host https://www.xxx.com.sg"

Comment: Please update your question with relevant content from the LogCat log, so we see the exact message.  Of course, that is one of those messages that generally means what it says - it usually means that the DNS server(s) used by the device simply can't resolve that name.  This error comes from Android itself, not from MobileFirst.  Any possibility that the KitKat and Lollipop devices are using different DNS servers than the others?